# How to run in debug mode a program that calls link with CreateProcess

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, linker-errors, createprocess

I am using `CreateProcess` to invoke `cl` and `link` to compile and link another C++ program (`TestProg.cxx`) into a DLL. I found the correct compilation and linkage options:

Compilation Options:

```
/W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _DEBUG /D _WINDOWS /D _USRDLL /D BUILDDLL_EXPORTS /D _WINDLL /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue /LD
```

Linkage Options:

```
/INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /Entry:DllMain
```

I call `CreateProcess` with:

```
if ( CreateProcess(full path to cl.exe, compilation options, NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,       NULL,NULL,&si,&pi) ) 
{
 //....
}
```

Running the application from VS tools prompt, it works and the dll is created.

But running it from the VS debugger I get the following LINK error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
```

or when the link libs are removed from the link options I get the following error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'
```

What am I doing wrong?

IMO it seems something is missing in the link options to run in debug mode, or the search path of debug mode lacks some directories. I don't know how to fix any of these cases.
I googled this for the last 1/2 day, but didn't find it. Using windows API is new to me.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like your environment is not set correctly. Make sure your `LIB` environment variable set and libraries are reachable through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're missing the environment variables which you get when running from the VS command line.
Part of this is also the library search path.

See `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio XX\Common7\vsvars32.bat` (depending on your VS version and installation path, which is specified in the `VS100COMNTOOLS` (or `VS90COMNTOOLS`, or which ever) environment variable.

Why are you doing this anyway? You could be using MSBuild to configure a project and build it. You can call MSBuild from your code, while the project is already configured for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I invoked vsvars32.bat from run prompt, this didn't help. I do this since I need to write a C++ program that reads a C++ file with a single function, runs it and counts how many lines were executed during the run. I found to do it by (1)modifying the source file as I read it so a counter value is increased before executing each line, adding a get function that returns the counter's value (2)to build the new program into a DLL (3)call from my program the DLL's function, first executing second getting the counter value. Please let me know if you see a better way. Thanks!

Comment: To build the new source code into a DLL you don't have to manually call the compiler and linker. You can create a Visual Studio project which includes the wanted source file(s) (or even manipulate the project files at runtime), and whenever you to build it, simply call devenv (Visual Studio's IDE) or MSBuild (if you're using VS 2010).

Comment: You can use msbuild with VS2008 also. It sounds like you are writing a profiler. Is that right?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan- Thanks, I am not writting a profier but trying to find input for code coverage for a given function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the location of the .lib files. Otherwise `link` does not know where to find your .lib files. You can do this either as command line arguments to `link` ([`/LIBPATH:dir`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xhzskbe.aspx)) or by setting the `LIB` environment variable.

Exactly where these .lib files are to be found depends on your installation. Open a Visual Studio command prompt and type `set LIB` to find out what is an appropriate setting for your installation.

Myself I'd be trying to avoid having to use `CreateProcess` for build automation since it has a pretty painful interface. I'd be looking for a higher level scripting language. I would also prefer to use `vcbuild` rather than calling `cl` and `link` by hand. But perhaps there is some good reason why you need to do this from C++ code that I am not aware of.